# "Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sdc1: Input/output error" while formatting my pendrive?

Tags: usb-drive

I have a Transcend 4 GB pen-drive. When I tried to format my pen-drive by right-clicking and selecting *format*, it showed:

```
Error creating file system: helper exited with exit code 1: Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sdc1: Input/output error
```

Then I tried to remove the contents of the pen-drive through:

```
rm -r software
```

The folder "software" is present in my pen-drive but the response was:

```
rm: cannot remove `software': Read-only file system
```

Comment: have you tried to format it using GParted? if you want I can post some instructions.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I tried many methods on Linux but failed. However, when I insert my pen drive into the computer running windows 7, the system offered to repair my pen drive; after I clicked 'OK', the system repaired my pen drive automatically.

Hope this may help you ...

Comment: I think we cannot offer solutions for the problems that must use another operating system that is not Ubuntu.